# My Dog's urine is drunk by big ants in large number

Tags: dogs

I have 18 months old male Rottie. Since last few days I have been notucing that when my dog pee, suddenly big ants come in a large number and start drinking it. Does it mean that my dog has some disease?

Comment: Could be a sign a diabetes.    Dog has glucose in his urine.

Comment: @Paparazzi Diabetes mellitus in an 18 month old? Certainly possible, but unlikely, especially if there are no other signs. I would not jump to any conclusions based on ants. Ants like salts, sugars, water, minerals, etc, all of which are found in urine. If you are concerned your dog has a disease, please see a veterinarian.